# Change the behaviour of cooked mode

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator

On a terminal, the cooked (canonical) mode allows the user to input in text, and the text is sent to the program when the user hits enter. While in cooked mode, the arrow keys don't work, and they just appear as ^[[A and similar, but backspace does.

So is it possible to allow arrow keys in the terminal? Ideally, I would be able to even specify my own default 'cooker' to use.

And if it is not possible, then why are all terminals like this?

If it helps, I use suckless terminal, but I would prefer a solution that works on all terminals.

Comment: It's an [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows).

Comment: I know why this behavior is the way it is, but that isn't the question - the question is how can I change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can run your commands with [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap), which provides readline's line editing, including arrow key movement.